# how to call a javascript function from codebehind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void addSchoolButtonClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey1", "SchoolSearchPopUp();", true);

        /*Some code*/
    }
```

I am developing a website in asp.net.At a Hyperlink onclick event i want to call a javascript `function"SchoolSearchPopUp()"`.this function is for creating a new popup window and it is working correctly.But my problem is ,a javascript function is calling or pop window opens only after executing the rest of the code in that function and that code need's some data that occurs as a result of popup.How can i create the popup before executing the rest of code in  that function.

Comment: C# runs on the **server**; Javascript runs on the **client**.  Your question is fundamentally impossible.  Use AJAX.

Comment: thanks.But my code is working.i just want to execute javascript before executing rest of the code in that function.now javascript is executing after executing rest of the code in that function.

Comment: Exactly.  That is fundamentally impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Change your postback trigger to something within the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think javascript can be called from code behind.  C# is running from the server and java is all client side.  There's a good explanation to a similar question here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1117189.aspx

If you need to execute a javascript function, you could try changing the hyperlink to a button and making use of the OnClientClick property.  This executes script client side rather than calling a method on the server.

```
     <asp:button id="Button1"
                 text="Click Here"
                 onclientclick="SchoolSearchPopUp()"
                 runat="server" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write JavaScript on the page to handle the click of the button first and then call to the page method on the server.
Add an OnClientClick attribute to your button element and run your JavaScript method from there:

```
<asp:Button ID="TestButton" OnClientClick="SchoolSearchPopup()" Text="Click Me" OnClick="addSchoolButtonClick" runat="server"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SchoolSearchPopup()
    {
        alert("Popup");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some javascript before your postback you will need to register your hyperlink's click event to a js method, then submit your post to the server after performing whatever client side logic you are looking to run. (not the other way around, using RegisterStartupScript)

Example:

```
$("#myHyperLink").click(function() {

    // do page logic, in your case show a modal window
    $("#myModalDivContainer").show();


    // submit your post to the server... replace targetClientID with ID of server control you're posting to
    __doPostBack('targetClientID', '');

   // NOTE: If you want to perform an AJAX request instead simply use some jQuery here instead. it's up to you how to handle the request from this point :)

});
```

Hope this helps!